# How do I fetch username so that I can put it in the page title using useLayoutEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am writing a simple app (in react native), where when the user navigates to the profile page the title of the page is the user's user name. Hence why I am using `useLayoutEffect` to set the options. I have something like:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
      props.navigation.setOptions({
        title: props.route.params.name,
      });
  }, [props.route.params.name]);
```

which works fine. Obviously, when I navigate to the "Profile" page, I have something like

```
<Tab.Screen
        name="My Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        listeners={(props) => ({
          tabPress: (event) => {
            props.navigation.navigate("Profile", {
              uid: currentUser.id
              name: currentUser.name,
            });
          },
        })}
      />
```

Which again works fine. **However** What if I navigate to some other profile? Do I always have to use

```
props.navigation.navigate("Profile", {
                  uid: user.id
                  name: user.name,
                });
```

That is to pass both user's id AND user's name to navigate to the profile page. To me that seems like unnecessary. Ideally I would like to pass user's id only (when navigate to the profile page) and from there to fetch user's name. Something like this:

```
props.navigation.navigate("Profile", {
                      uid: user.id
                    });
```

and then inside the profile screen:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
          props.navigation.setOptions({
            title: fetchUsersNamebasedOnId()
          });
      }, [props.route.params.id]);
```

Is this possible? I tried the following:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      props.navigation.setOptions({
        title: getName(),
      });
    })();
  }, [props.route.params.name]);
```

and then `getName` is async function which returns the name. However it doesn't work for me. Is it possible to fetch the name inside "Profile" screen and to put it in the title of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You are quite close to it.

When you want to use the `async` function you have to wait till the request is done. For that, you use the `await` keyword. See the example below:

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const setName = async () => {
      const title = await getName(props.route.params.id)
      props.navigation.setOptions({
        title,
      })
    }
    setName()
  }, [props.route.params.id])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the above, but title comes as undefined. I added my getName() function in my question, if that helps. I also console.log(snapshot.data().name) and yes, it returns the name, but for some reason I can not assign it to the title

Comment: Add `id` to your `getName` function. So it will be `await getName(props.route.params.id)` inside component and then inside `const getName = async (id) => {....` you probably need to use `doc(id)`.